# Posts appear in footer section of website

Tags: wordpress

My blog posts appear in the footer section of my website.  I've looked at my code, and I can't figure out where the problem is stemming from.  I've included a link to a dropbox file that includes all of my current theme folders, as well as a screenshot of what my site currently looks like.  If anyone has any solutions I would appreciate it!

[dropbox.com/sh/jvafvxqylg8wuye/AACSatmJfpbLa02-bsbn0yH6a?dl=‌​0](http://dropbox.com/sh/jvafvxqylg8wuye/AACSatmJfpbLa02-bsbn0yH6a?dl=%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the template files and without seeing the outputted HTML, this could be caused by mismatching element declarations. In the header.php the `<header>` element is declared but never closed. Try closing the header element with `</header>` in the end of the header.php

Comment: I have now closed the </header> tag.  However I still have the same problem.  The posts appear in the footer area.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a styling issue - have you tried adding `clear: both;` to `.site-footer {}` in your CSS?

**EDIT**:

I'd suggest that you wrap your content in a container that has `clear: both;` assigned to it - this will prevent your articles from clashing with anything else on the page.

Comment: You're most welcome. I've updated my answer with a more robust solution for you.